# Error al guardar imagen en la galeria React cordova

Tags: java, android, reactjs, cordova

Actualmente, estoy utilizando el siguiente plugin, pero me da error al guardar la imagen en la gallería

https://socket.dev/npm/package/cordova-plugin-save-image-gallery

Error

> 2023-01-19 12:21:47.296 6745-6838/com.prosur.nacionalseguros
> E/SaveImageToGallery: An exception occured while saving image:
> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /storage/emulated/0/PagoQr_2023019122147.png: open failed: EPERM
> (Operation not permitted) 2023-01-19 12:21:47.297
> 6745-6838/com.prosur.nacionalseguros E/PluginManager: Uncaught
> exception from plugin
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.toString()' on a null object reference
> at com.agomezmoron.saveImageGallery.SaveImageGallery.saveBase64Image(SaveImageGallery.java:147)
> at com.agomezmoron.saveImageGallery.SaveImageGallery.execute(SaveImageGallery.java:66)
> at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(Cordova
>
> Plugin.java:98)
> at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:132)
> at com.getcapacitor.MessageHandler.callCordovaPluginMethod(MessageHandler.java:123)
> at com.getcapacitor.MessageHandler.postMessage(MessageHandler.java:61)
> at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
> at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
> at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

Dejo el código.

```
const params = {
 data: props.hash.replace("data:image/png;base64,", ""),
 prefix: “PruebaQr_",
 format: "PNG",
 mediaScanner: false,
};
var params = {data: props.hash, prefix: 'PagoQr_', 
 format: 'JPG', quality: 80, mediaScanner: true};
 window.imageSaver.saveBase64Image(params,
 function (filePath) {
  alert('Archivo fue salvado en: ' + filePath);
 },
 function (msg) {
  alert('Ocurrìo un error al salvar el archivo ' + msg);
 }
);
```

Comment: Hola Damian, recuerda que es importante agregar el còdigo para que la comunidad tenga mejor idea de lo que sucede, saludos.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario Jorge, tienes razon. 
Dejo el código. 
const params = {
 data: props.hash.replace("data:image/png;base64,", ""),
 prefix: “PruebaQr_",
 format: "PNG",
 mediaScanner: false,
};
var params = {data: props.hash, prefix: 'PagoQr_', 
 format: 'JPG', quality: 80, mediaScanner: true};
 window.imageSaver.saveBase64Image(params,
 function (filePath) {
  alert('Archivo fue salvado en: ' + filePath);
 },
 function (msg) {
  alert('Ocurrìo un error al salvar el archivo ' + msg);
 }
);

Answer (score 0):

El [plugin](https://socket.dev/npm/package/cordova-plugin-save-image-gallery) que usas permite guardar datos base64 como imagen en el dispositivo.

El problema que presentas:

> PluginManager: Uncaught exception from plugin
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'java.lang.String java.io.File.toString()' on a null object reference

se debe a que algunos de los parámetros, principalmente `data` no tiene valor o tiene un valor null.

```
   var params = {data: base64String, prefix: 'myPrefix_', format: 'JPG', quality: 80, mediaScanner: true};
```

Agrega como indica la documentaciòn una validaciòn para evitar este error y para imprimir en la consola el problema:

```
var params = {data: base64String, prefix: 'myPrefix_', format: 'JPG', quality: 80, mediaScanner: true};
    window.imageSaver.saveBase64Image(params,
        function (filePath) {
          console.log('Archivo fue salvado en: ' + filePath);
        },
        function (msg) {
          console.error('Ocurrìo un error al salvar el archivo');
        }
      );
```